# MSCaptcha image not displaying after migrating my website

Tags: .net, captcha

Here is the web.config code.

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.captchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha" />
  </httpHandlers>
....
</system.web>

<stsem.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="MSCaptcha.captchaImageHandler" verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.captchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  </handlers>
....
</system.webServer>
```

and on my webpage:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="MSCaptcha" Namespace="MSCaptcha" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<cc1:CaptchaControl ID="CaptchaControl1" runat="server" Height="20px" 
                    Width="180px" CaptchaLength="5" BackColor="White" 
                    EnableViewState="False" />
```

When I view the HTMLL source, on both my development environment, I get the following code for the Captcha image (just with different GUIDs):

```
<img src="CaptchaImage.axd?guid=d2b42e49-30e3-4b1e-9e71-92a159d671e6" border="0" alt="Captcha" width="180" height="50" />
```

I can't see a CaptchaImage.axd file on either website (VS2010 project or my live webserver), but the MSCaptcha.dll and MSCaptcha.xml exist in the bin folder in both environments.

I have tried adding the following code as well, from a post I found elsewhere:

```
<location path="CaptchaImage.axd">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Still I get just get the text "X Catcha" or "Captcha" where the image should be.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem until I add the following to the handler line in web.config: preCondition="integratedMode"

In the section system.webserver/handlers.

Comment: This fixed it on a site we moved today.

Answer (score 0):

The dll may require full trust and if you are running this in a shared environment chances are it will not work.  Often times you can find or make the dll a medium trust, etc. and get it to work.  Also, if you are running this under IIS7, try setting the application pool to classic mode instead of integrated.